# Are questions regarding website policies on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, private-beta

I voted to close [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/925/which-photo-storage-sites-allow-for-hot-linking) as it seemed to me to be too localised as site policies change over time. However, the owner disagrees, as when policies change the answers can just be edited.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't close as "too localized" on that basis. *Any* answer to a question *can* change. Technology itself changes constantly. That doesn't make the question too localized, or we would have virtually nothing to talk about.

I would agree if, for example, photo sites notoriously changed their bandwidth caps daily. A better example of "too localized" is something more along the lines of *"how much does it cost to buy X."* Obviously too localized.

But not in this case.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/925/which-photo-storage-sites-allow-hotlinking#comment536_925):

> @Simon Brown that's why SE-type sites allow you to edit questions and answers. Because the information changes over time. :-)

Site policies will always change.  The crux of Stack Exchange is to be able to edit that information when it changes.

How many Facebook questions would have to be closed because their privacy policy is ever changing?  By definition, any privacy question would be closed as too localized.

Answer (score -2):

As of March 2023 the question is closed as

> Application/website recommendations are off-topic and out of scope.

because it's not specific about a single web application.

If it was about a single web application, it still nowadays will not not-be on-topic, but it will be closed as

> Questions that ask about the internal policies, technologies, and algorithms of web application companies are off-topic because only the company or its developers truly know the answer. Please see: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163).

Comment: I agree with the recommendation part, but I don't agree that this question should be closed anyway, because it is about internal policies. A policy to allow or disallow hotlinking is not an internal policy. For example, the question: "does imgur allow hotlinking?" should remain open. But the question "why does imgur block hotlinking?" should be closed, because we as the community cannot know what the company or the developers were thinking.