# Can something like "Why does LINE demand to verify a cellphone number when I start the application on my laptop?" be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask something along the lines of

> Why does LINE demand to verify a cellphone number when I start the application on my laptop? Is there any way to avoid this; register as a new user of the application and use it on my laptop without giving them a cellphone number?

but my gut instinct is that it's not really op-topic here. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, questions that ask "why" about internal policies of the companies/development teams behind web applications are off-topic on this site, actually we have a custom close reason for that kind of questions.

Related

- [Are questions regarding website policies on-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/88163)
- [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)
- [Do we need a close reason for questions asking about proprietary/non-public information or policies?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4614/88163)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!